# How can I get the image path of primng upload?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

Using the primeng FileUpload I don't know how to get the path of the file

```
<p-fileUpload  name="demo[]"  accept="image/*" (onUpload)="onBasicUpload($event)" [auto]="true"></p-fileUpload>
```

How I could get the image path ??? e.g "C:\User\images\test.jpg"

Comment: You can’t get that path. That would be a security issue.

Comment: thank you for response.